# Piechart not show label if the value is a low percentage

Tags: php, cakephp, graph, highcharts

I have a pie chart with many different kinds of values, resulting in almost 40 slices and the majority of them are below 10%. Is it possible to now display the label on the pie graph for only these low values, but show the value for the bigger slices?

Comment: You will have to be more specific than this. What graph library are you using? What code have you tried so far that is not working?

Comment: I'm using highcharts, I don't have any code because I have no idea at all how to do this. I tried google searching for similar things but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use datalabels formatter, and check if datalabale should be displayed or not (i.e condition based on value or different parameter).

Simple example:

```
dataLabels:{
     formatter:function(){
            if(this.y > 10)
                 return this.value; 
            else
                 return null //empty datalabel
     }
}
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: It seems like every time I google a Highcharts question, @Sebastian is the one with the answer. If you're not on payroll yet you should be.